# LALR(1) Parser Not Parsing The Text At All

Tags: parsing, lalr

I have to admit I'm an absolute newbie in this and might not even understand what I am doing.

I am trying to make a grammar that at least contains grammar from BABA IS YOU, and if possible expands on it. I am using this tool to debug my grammar: http://jsmachines.sourceforge.net/machines/lalr1.html

Admittedly, my grammar is currently not LALR(1) (as seen by many shift/reduce conflicts which I am unsure on how to properly resolve).

So, when I enter "RED AND BLUE BABA IS YOU" into the parser, this is what I expect to see:

[image: "RED AND BLUE BABA IS YOU" Expected Tree]

And yet what I see is:

[image: Unexpected outcome]

I have no idea at where to dig to start understanding my problem and I need help with at least that

The Grammar I use is this: https://pastebin.com/5MHZrFLe

```
sentence' -> sentence
 
sentence -> give
 
give -> giver property
giver -> noun IS
 
selector -> adjective noun
 
multinoun -> noun AND
multinoun -> multinoun AND
multinoun -> multinoun noun
 
multiadjective -> adjective AND
multiadjective -> multiadjective AND
multiadjective -> multiadjective adjective
 
noun -> multinoun
noun -> selector
 
noun -> BABA
noun -> KEKE
noun -> ROBOT
 
adjective -> RED
adjective -> BLUE
adjective -> GREEN
 
property -> YOU
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for the token `AND` in that sentence to be recognised, there would have to be a derivation sequence leading from `sentence'` to `multiadjective`. There is no such sequence, as can easily be verified by doing a simple reachability graph (which is just a DFS).

That makes `multiadjective` useless in that grammar. It's slightly surprising that the tool you use doesn't warn you about that.

That's not the case for `multinoun`, which is reachable through the `noun -> multinoun` production. However, that creates a number of ambiguities, leading to shift/reduce conflicts. One example:

```
noun -> multinoun -> multinoun AND
```

vs

```
noun -> multinoun -> noun AND -> multinoun AND
```

The general pattern for a bottom-up grammar representing a list of token-separated items is:

```
list -> item
list -> list separator item
```

In such a grammar, the list is included in an outer production using the non-terminal `list`, not `item`. Adding `item -> list` in order to be able to refer to it as `item` leads to the same ambiguities as your `noun` non-terminal, which more or less reproduces this error.

Comment: Thanks! also thanks for giving the way to think about thiss